# Formatting 'Y-m-d H:i:s' with strtotime

Tags: php

I want to format `$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` to `$time` using `strtotime($datetime)` for display like `2016-01-20 11:16:31` But it does not work. How do I fix that?

**CODE**

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$time = strtotime($datetime); 
echo $time; 
echo $datetime;
```

**My code given output like this :**

```
1453263391 // $time
2016-01-20 11:16:31 // $datetime
```

Comment: strtotime  gives Unix timestamp 
$datetime gives you expected format there

date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: I want to set $time format from $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); .

Comment: Date and time just like 2016-01-20 11:16:31

Comment: `strtotime` doesn't give you `time` like you expect

Comment: date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  this is a date time format dude

Comment: I know that, But 2016-01-20 11:16:31 just a example. My $time is echo 1453263391 not Y-m-d H:i:s like $datetime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtotime` doesn't give you ***time*** like you expect. If you just need time remove the date placeholders

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$time = date('H:i:s');
```

`strtotime` is something else. It converts a properly formatted date time string into a UNIX timestamp which you seemingly don't need here.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` return unixtimestamp, so with unix timestamp you can custom your own date format with provided timestamp.

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //or can be like $datetime = '2014-09-08 14:54:21';
$unix = strtotime($datetime);

$date = date('Y-m-d',$unix);
$time = date('H:i:s',$unix);
$hour = date('H',$unix);
$minute = date('i',$unix);
$month = date('m',$unix); //etc
```